# GUI - icon - change possible? Python 3

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

I'm trying to change my icon on my GUI screen - you know, the one at the top left of the window. I have used multiple ico files, but nothing works!

I would really appreciate it if someone would come and help me. I am using Tkinter.

Comment: What framework are you using? Tkinter?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the tk interface module @MalikBrahimi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set window icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon)