# How to change logo in tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an asksaveasfilename dialog in python so the user can select a filelocation to save a file to. I have all of the functionality working fine, but when the window opens there is a logo in the top left corner that I would like to change to match the logo of my program. None of the properties that I found [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) allow me to change this logo. Is there a way to modify this property of asksaveasfilename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem with help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon). If I put the following code before my `asksaveasfilename` the logo will appear in the top left corner of the dialog.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()    
root.withdraw()
root.iconbitmap(r'images\\Logo.ico)
```

Comment: how is this related to pygtk?