# Why do I always have to rewrite .iconbitmap() command in order for it to work?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, anaconda, spyder, ico

I am using Tkinter to make a GUI application and am using the .iconbitmap() to specify my own .ico file instead of Tkinter's default. I am using Spyder.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

#program

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Users\Kelin\Documents\Python Scripts\workspace\AGN\AGN.ico')
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

However, the first time I run the program, it throws this error:

```
TclError: bitmap "c:\Users\Kelin\Documents\Python Scripts\workspace\AGN\AGN.ico" not defined
```

From what I have read on this site (specifically, the question this was identified as a duplicate of), this can be caused when the .ico file is in the same directory as the .py file, and/or the full path isn't specified. However, as you can see the full path is specified and the icon is not in the same folder as the .py file. Furthermore, if I comment out the .iconbitmap() command, run the program, close it, uncomment the command and run it again, it works and uses my custom icon. If I restart the kernel, it throws the error again.

I assume it has something to do with something being loaded when I successfully run the program, can anyone explain this to me and offer a solution? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set window icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon)

Comment: You've misread the linked duplicate. The reason indicated in the accepted answer states that the problem occurs *when the icon is in the same directory*, not when it's not.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.

Comment: I moved the .ico file to a completely different directory, and double checked that the paths are correct, and it is still giving the same error :/

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. Please consider updating the question (without the "edit" marks - just rewrite the relevant part) - hopefully someone else will have the solution. Good luck!