# How is it possible to change the icon on the title bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a question.

How is it possible to change the icon on the title bar, on a tkinter window?

I've tried `.iconbitmap()`. but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538416/4577427

that answer works fine, I tested it with a .exe and it took the icon of the .exe (didn't have a .ico handy)
[image: tkinter_using_factorio_ico]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Program Files\Factorio\bin\x64\Factorio.exe')
root.mainloop()
```

it needs the whole path, not just a part

Comment: how did u do it without putting full location path . if the ico in current directory

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R I needed the whole path for the file. Also I prefixed the string with an "r" to make Python ignore special characters (eg \\).

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R you can't just use the name instead of the full path, unless the icon is in the main directory of the project. If the python file is in any sub directory and the icon is also in that, still you will need either the full path, or the relative path (relative to the main folder) to that icon.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use An '.ico' File To Change The Title Icon.

Heres The Code

```
root.iconbitmap(r'E:\\Projects\\Applications\\Nex Calculator\\icon.ico')
```

The Result:
[The Icon Popped Up!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jjIp.png)