# Python turtle: How to change icons

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I would like to change two graphical icons related to turtle graphics using Python:

a) One that shows up at the top left corner of the canvas window as in [here](https://s22.postimg.org/tkjaxmh41/image.png). I believe this is coming from tk itself.

[image]

b) The icon on the desktop as in [here](https://s13.postimg.org/n7ol0mdpz/icon.png) (in Windows).

[image]

Can this be done through python code itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set window icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon)