# Icon Mismatch Between Task Bar & The Clicable App Icon

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I have this problem that I couldn't be able to resolve. Basically, I successfully created a Python GUI which I packaged it using pyinstaller by issuing this command:

```
 C:\Python27x86\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --noupx --icon=myicon.ico mygui.py
```

The icon has changed successfully but only in the clickable app but not on the Task Bar, the icon on the task bar looks like the one found below and different from my icon, how can I change the icon only on the Task bar?

I am using Python2.7 32 bit and the O.S is Windows 7 Professionals

Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding the following code:

```
root.iconbitmap(r'myicon.ico')
```

Now, both Task Bar and the Clicable Icon App are matched! Solution inspired from this:
[Set window icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon)