# Which file formats can I use for tkinter icons?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, .ico

I know this might be obvious, but in tkinter you can set an icon, but I have found it really hard to find one. I just wanted to know if you have to use the `.ico` format for the file or if there is a way to use `.png` or `.jpeg` files.

Currently I have

```
window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Weclome!")
window.geometry("200x300")
window.wm_iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
window.configure(background = "Black")
```

That is the whole setup I have and I just want to know about line 4:

```
window.wm_iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
```

Thanks for responding to my question, although i am sorry for not spending more time looking into the question rather than just asking here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Let's start by reading the documentation!

The documentation at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconbitmap-method) says the following regarding `iconbitmap(bitmap=None)`

> Sets or gets the icon bitmap to use when this window is iconified. This method is ignored by some window managers (including Windows).
>
> Note that this method can only be used to display **monochrome icons**. To display a *color icon*, put it in a `Label` widget and display it using the `iconwindow` method instead.
>
> Same as `wm_iconbitmap`.

So here's the documentation about `iconwindow(window=None)`:

> Sets or gets the icon window to use as an icon when this window is iconified. This method is ignored by some window managers (including Windows).
>
> Same as `wm_iconwindow`.
>
> `window`
>
> ```
> The new icon window. If omitted, the current window is returned.
> ```

According to this [other documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Wm-class.html#wm_iconbitmap), which actually says the same things as the docstrings of the homonymous method for `tkinter` in (at least) Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6:

> `wm_iconbitmap(self, bitmap=None, default=None)`
>
> Set bitmap for the iconified widget to `bitmap`. Return the bitmap if None is given.
>
> Under Windows, the `default` parameter can be used to set the icon for the widget and any descendents that don't have an icon set explicitly. `default` can be the relative path to a `.ico` file (example: `root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico')` ). See Tk documentation for more information.

So here's the original Tk documentation:

> [`wm iconbitmap window ?bitmap?`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M31)
>
> If bitmap is specified, then it names a bitmap in the standard forms accepted by Tk (see the [`Tk_GetBitmap`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetBitmap.htm) manual entry for details). This bitmap is passed to the window manager to be displayed in window's icon, and the command returns an *empty string*. If an empty string is specified for `bitmap`, then any current icon bitmap is canceled for `window`. If `bitmap` is specified then the command returns an *empty string*. Otherwise, it returns the name of the current icon bitmap associated with `window`, or an empty string if `window` has no icon bitmap.

From my understanding of `Tcl`, here `window` is your toplevel window (either an instance of `Tk` or `Toplevel`).

> On the Windows operating system, an additional flag is supported:
>
> ```
> wm iconbitmap window ?-default? ?image?
> ```
>
> If the `-default` flag is given, the icon is applied to all toplevel windows (existing and future) to which no other specific icon has yet been applied.
>
> In addition to bitmap image types, a full path specification to any file which contains a valid Windows icon is also accepted (usually `.ico` or `.icr` files), or any file for which the shell has assigned an icon.
>
> Tcl will first test if the file contains an icon, then if it has an assigned icon, and finally, if that fails, test for a bitmap.

Not very concrete and thus helpful answer so far.

---

### My conclusion

The `iconbitmap` function (or method, depending on the programming language) should be used to set a [**bitmap**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) image to the window when the window is iconified.

On Windows you're allowed to set a full path specification to any file which contains a [*valid Windows icon*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485(v=vs.85).aspx) is also accepted (usually `.ico` or `.icr` files), or any file for which the shell has assigned an icon.

#### So which images are bitmaps?

1. [`xbm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) and [`xpm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) (for *X Window System*)

   According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap#Other_bitmap_file_formats) to which I linked "bitmap" to above:

   > The *X Window System* uses a similar `xbm` format for *black-and-white* images, and `xpm` for color images.
   >   ...
2. [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)
3. [Netpbm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)
4. [`.wbmp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol_Bitmap_Format)
5. [ILBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILBM)

   ...

So most of the bitmap file formats are **not** cross-platform! In other words, if someone tells you to use a `xbm` image for the icon, it may not work on your platform because `xbm` are bitmaps for *X Window System*.

***Note:** even after this answer you may still have problems!*

---

### Other possible useful articles

- [Set window icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon)
- [tkinter TclError: error reading bitmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling a lot to find an answer too but finally I peeked into the source code of idle3.6 where I found the following piece of code:

```
# set application icon
icondir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Icons')
if system() == 'Windows':
    iconfile = os.path.join(icondir, 'idle.ico')
    root.wm_iconbitmap(default=iconfile)
else:
    ext = '.png' if TkVersion >= 8.6 else '.gif'
    iconfiles = [os.path.join(icondir, 'idle_%d%s' % (size, ext))
                 for size in (16, 32, 48)]
    icons = [PhotoImage(master=root, file=iconfile)
             for iconfile in iconfiles]
    root.wm_iconphoto(True, *icons)
```

I searched through all files in the idlelib folder for .ico and .png using the [rummage](https://pypi.org/project/rummage/) software.

So finally I managed to get the window icon working (on GNU-linux with TkVersion>=8.6) with the following two lines:

```
icon = PhotoImage(master=root, file='icon.png')
root.wm_iconphoto(True, icon)
```

where I put the icon directly in my application folder.

From the idle code it seems to me that on Windows still only .ico files are supported.

Comment: I accidentally answered the question I was looking for myself. However, despite the question asked here is slightly different, I think my answer is still quite useful.