# Set a titlebar icon for a turtle window

Tags: python, python-turtle

Is there a way to set a titlebar icon for the turtle module? I want to have something like this:

[image]

I want to put a titlebar icon and I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

`turtle` is based on `tkinter`. Delving to the source code of `turtle` will reveal that in order to reach the underlying `tkinter` bases you need:

```py
import turtle

root = turtle.Screen()._root
```

And now this `root` is actually a `tkinter`'s `Tk` object which has the [`iconbitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538416/6045800) method:

```py
root.iconbitmap("path_to.ico")
```

Comment: Tried in [Replit](https://replit.com/@RixTheTyrunt/buildsguy?v=1), got: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    tkroot.iconbitmap("buildsguy.ico")
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "buildsguy.ico" not defined```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
import turtle
import tkinter
turtle.title('Hello Tux')
img = tkinter.Image("photo", file="/usr/share/pixmaps/tuxpaint.png")
turtle._Screen._root.iconphoto(True, img)
```

You have to call some function to force the creation of the root `tkinter` window, the most obvious is setting the title. Then you can access standard `tkinter` functions to set the icon.

Comment: Your method works. Thank you!