# tkinter iconbitmap don't work and wm_iconbitmap also don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, fedora-33

using python 3.9.1 and tkinter from fedora cinnamon repos, trying to set window's icon with tkinter running this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My Tkinter app")
        self.iconbitmap("python.ico")
        self.geometry("400x200+10+10")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

the ico image used is this: [python.ico](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Tkinter-GUI-Application-Development-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter01/python.ico), but get this message when run the code:

```
self.iconbitmap("python.ico")
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2072, in wm_iconbitmap
return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "python.ico" not defined
```

already tried to use wm_iconbitmap instead iconbitmap buth don't work, How could change window icon?

The solution in the post [sugested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/why-isnt-ico-file-defined-when-setting-windows-icon) is put an r letter before the "" in the iconbitmap method, I tried but don't work for my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't .ico file defined when setting window's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/why-isnt-ico-file-defined-when-setting-windows-icon)

Comment: @TheLizzard, the solution in that post is put an r letter befor the "" in the iconbitmap method, I tried but don't work for my case.

Comment: Have you tried putting in the full path as in: `"C:\Python32\DLLs\py.ico"`?

Comment: @TheLizzard, yes I tried, using the Linux form path.

Comment: This is just to cover all of the basis but are you sure that you are running the program from the same dir as where the picture is located?

Comment: @TheLizzard, yes, use ls Linux command to verify that python code and ico image are both inside the same directory.

Comment: I am out of ideas :(

Comment: How did you make the `ico` file? By simply renaming a file into .ico? That wont work, you will have to use a proper conversion tool.

Comment: @CoolCloud, the link shared in my post, from there I get the ico file.

Comment: In windows 10 with Python 3.7 the code run perfectly, maybe in Linux can't set window icon...

Comment: Maybe, not sure

Comment: ICO file is supported in Windows. Use XBM format in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

At first convert python.ico to python.xbm (for example using GIMP).
Then prepend the filename with "@". For example:

```
self.iconbitmap("@python.xbm")
```

I have checked this code in UbuntuMate and SuSE Linux, python3.6